# $n^{2}th$ Fibonacci number

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics

### Question

> Let $F_k$  denote the $k_{th}$ Fibonacci number.  Then, the $n^{2}th$ Fibonacci number $F_n$    can be  computed in $O(\log n)$ time.

#### My Approach/Confusion

Above question is taken from MIT quiz .I am solving it just to practice and build the concept.

I know that Recurrence relation for Fibonacci number is

$F(k)=F(k-1)+F(k-2)$  solving this , $F(k)=O(2^{k})$

I am not getting how the $n^{2}th$ Fibonacci number $F_n$    can be  computed in $O(\log n)$ time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The challenge of finding fast algorithms for computing Fibonacci numbers gives interesting insights into how one should best compute recursively defined entities. See https://www.nayuki.io/page/fast-fibonacci-algorithms for a short introduction.

In this case, you should use the identity

$$\left[ \begin{array}{ll} 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 \end{array}\right]^n = \left[ \begin{array}{ll} F(n+1) & F(n) \\
F(n) & F(n-1)  \end{array}  \right]$$

and exponentiation by repeated squaring of matrices.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use the Fibonacci relation on the terms in the Fibonacci relation:
$$
F(k)=F(k-1)+F(k-2)\\
=2F(k-2)+F(k-3)\\
=3F(k-3)+2F(k-4)
$$
and so on. If you do it a few more steps, you should recognize the pattern in the coefficients. Stop at the most convenient step, and then use this same method to calculate those terms. In the end, this gives you an $O(\log k)$ algorithm.

Comment: The pattern is that the coefficients are just Fibonacci numbers. A result of the form $F(k)=aF(k-n)+bF(k-n-1)$ won't, I think, get $F(n)$ in $O(\log n)$ time.

Comment: @J.G. If $a$ and $b$ themselves are equal to $F(k-n)$ and $F(k-n-1)$ (or something close to it; I haven't counted exactly), and then you use recursion on these, i.e. calculate all these (fewer than) four numbers the same way, then you see that we only calculate terms of the form $F(k/2^n\pm1)$ (up to some rounding). That makes this $O(\log n)$.

Comment: @Arthur You can use formulas of this type (which follow immediately from the matrix identity) to essentially derive the repeated squaring from my answer in a somewhat ad hoc way.  However, I think that matrices make the logic clearer.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Aaron I think the logic here is clear enough. The implementation of the matrix multiplication may be a whole lot easier, though.

Answer (score 1):

The recurrence relation can actually find $F_n$ in $O(n)$ if you keep both $F_k$ and $F_{k-1}$ in memory.

However, a more efficient method is to use the matrix formula for the Fibonacci numbers.  If $A$ is the matrix that has a $0$ in the top left corner and $1$ elsewhere, then $A^n=\pmatrix{F_{n-1} & F_n \\ F_n & F_{n+1}}$.  However, you can compute the $n$th power by repeated squaring (or multiplying by $A$), and this takes approximately $\log n$ steps.

Comment: sir if $n^{th}$ power takes $\log n $ steps . then how much do $n^{2}th$ would take?

Comment: @laura $\log(n^2)=2\log(n)\in O(\log n)$.

Comment: yes sir , thanks a lot :)

Comment: @laura I should add that the word "approximately" can be strengthened.  If $n$ when written in binary has $k$ total digits and $m$ of them are $1$, then you will need $k+m$ matrix multiplications (within like 1 or 2).  This is as much as $2\log(n)$, but doesn't change the order of magnitude.

Answer (score 1):

the $n^{th}$ Fibonacci number is

$\frac {\phi^n - \phi'^n}{\phi - \phi'}$

Where $\phi = \frac {1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $\phi' = \frac {1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$

That doesn't take very many steps at all.

Comment: Your $\phi$ and $\phi'$ are equal. Also, technically, raising to the power of $n$ is an $O(\log n)$ operation, assuming multiplication is constant time.

Comment: Large powers of $\phi$ probably won't be computed accurately enough to get the exact value of $F_n$. Since we want $F_{n^2}$, the maximum $n$ for which your algorithm is safe isn't very large.

Comment: I more often see it typeset as $\varphi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $\psi=\frac{1\color{red}{-}\sqrt{5}}{2}$.  The apostrophe to delineate between the two doesnt' appear well with exponents.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)